# Import angular components by string name

Tags: html, angular, components

I want to display a angular-component by inserting its name as a string.I tried the way through viewContainerRef, but it is not working. I load the component string name from a json and then I want to render it as an component, which is already created in the root level of the app.

Overview:

This is a json-file with the desired componentName:

```json
{
    "planeGeo": {
        "topics": {
            "Basics": {
                "Intro":
                {
                    "title": "Intro to areas",
                    "routerLink": "Intro",
                    "htmlCode": "assets/html/plane1.html",
                    "componentName" : "<app-lorem></app-lorem>"
                },
                "Calculation":
                {
                    "title": "Calculation of areas",
                    "routerLink": "Calc",
                    "htmlCode": "assets/html/plane2.html",
                    "componentName" : "<app-test></app-test>"
                }
          }
}
```

For now I load the path of an html-file with this method:

```js
getCurrentContent() {
    const jsonPath = `assets/models/${this.currentSubject}.json`;
    this.http.get<any>(jsonPath).subscribe((data) => {
      const htmlPath =
        data[this.currentSubject]['topics'][this.topic][this.subtopic][
          'htmlCode'
        ];
      if (htmlPath) {
        this.http
          .get(htmlPath, { responseType: 'text' })
          .subscribe((htmlData) => {
            this.currentContent =
              this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlData);
          });
      } else {
        console.error('HTML-Code nicht gefunden.');
      }
    });
  }
```

which is then inserted in the corresponding html-file:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="currentContent"></div>
```

What I want to do is loading a complete compononent instead of a single html-file, because of the limitations with css and js-logic.

I tried the following:

```js
getCurrentContentAsComponent() {
    const jsonPath = `assets/models/${this.currentSubject}.json`;
    this.http.get<any>(jsonPath).subscribe((data) => {
      const componentName =
        data[this.currentSubject]['topics'][this.topic][this.subtopic][
          'componentName'
        ];
      console.log(componentName);

      if (componentName) {
        this.loadComponent(componentName);
      } else {
        console.error('Komponentenname nicht gefunden.');
      }
    });
  }

  loadComponent(componentName: any) {
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentName);
    console.log(componentRef);
  }
```

, but here I get error msgs that my passed value is not a component (what is true, because it is a string at this moment).

The component is already created, i.e. `<app-lorem>`.

The console output says that the string is `<app-lorem></app-lorem>`, but it its component isn't rendered.

My question is: How can I handle the string name to be rendered as an component?

Comment: Could you please add some code snippets that would explain what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried so far? A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help to answer your question as well.